# Is there an hotel price search engine that also searches nearby cities?

Tags: budget, online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

I use often booking search engines or price comparison for hotels.

One feature I miss is the possibility to search in nearby cities. Either specifying a radius or by system suggestion. Most times I don't mind staying in a nearby city/location if prices are good enough and good transport connections exist.

I know I can do several searches but it would be nicer if the system sugested and shows one listing only instead of having to iterate through several listings and looking at maps for nearby cities.

Is there an hotel search engine that gives this information?

Comment: Can you point out what resources you have tried that do *not* do this? My experience with portals such as HRS is rather that I typically search for hotels near a particular address and sort by distance. At first, I am then usually happy to see that there is plenty of choice, just to notice that after the first few results, hotels are often 50km or more away, in a totally different city.

Comment: Are you looking at a specific region/country?

Answer (score 5):

[Booking.com](http://booking.com) does exactly this.

I just did a test looking for a place to stay in Antwerp.  You have to scroll down for a while on the results screen and then you will see this in the left-hand column:

[image]

(It's beneath all the filters you can set)